# How to use properties that are not in the base class

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, polymorphism

**Base Class**

```
public class Base
    {
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Tax()
        {
            return Price / 2;
        }
    }
```

**Derived Class**

```
public class Car : Base
{
    public int Power { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }

    public Car(string brand, int power, int price, string name)
    {
        Brand = brand;
        Power = power ;
        Price = price;
        Name = name;
    }
```

**Cart Class**

```
 public class Cart
    {
        private List<Base> list = new List<Base>();
        public int TotalPrice()
        {
            int sumPrice = 0;
            foreach (Base item in list)
            {
                sumPrice += item.Tax();
            }
            return sumPrice;
        }
        public void Add(Base baseClass)
        {
            list.Add(baseClass);
        }
```

**Controller**

```
     Cart cart = new Cart();
     Car car = new Car("BMW", 10, 100, "John");
     cart.Add(car);
     return View("Index", cart.TotalPrice().ToString());
```

I create objects from a derived class and add it to the cart.

**Car car = new Car("BMW", 10, 100, "John");**

But I use base class when I list cars in Cart class.

**private List < Base > list = new List< Base >();**

I don't get any errors, but what I want to know is that even though there are no "Brand" and "Power" properties in the base class, I can still add them to the base class and list them.

public void Add(Base base)

{

list.Add(base);

}

Comment: Just cast the base class to car to access the properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From inheritance, a `Car` **is-a** `Base`, so it can be added to `list` (a `List<Base>`).

*can still add them to the base class...*
`Brand` and `Power` are properties of `Car`, not `Base`.

*and list them...*
`Brand` and `Power` are not referenced anywhere after the construction of a `Car`.  See what happens if you try:

```
    public int TotalPrice()
    {
        int sumPrice = 0;
        foreach (Base item in list)
        {
            sumPrice += item.Tax();
            item.Power = 42; // <--- try to add this line
        }
        return sumPrice;
    }
```

Comment: I can't use "Power" and "Brand" properties in the Cart class, but when I run it in Debug mode, I see "Power" and "Brand" properties in the list and in the Add method. 
https://i.imgur.com/YwHogLz.jpeg
Sorry, I'm new, so I'm having trouble understanding some OOP concepts.

Comment: No worries - debugging will display all of the properties of the instance.  It just happens the instance is a `Car`.  However, the list is of `List<Base>`, so each item in that list **is-a** `Base`. But each item in the list is not necessarily a `Car`.  Try adding another class that extends `Base` such as `Food`, with its own properties such as `ServingsPerCcontainer` and `CaloriesPerServing`.  Look at casting and instanceof, but be wary since using them usually indicates a design issue.

Comment: Thanks, you have been very helpful.